# Как привязать приложение к устройству?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать что б один аккаунт работал только на одном устройстве?

На сколько я знаю автоматически получать номер телефона получаеться не всегда.

И еще ньюанс в том что регистрация проходит на сторонней платформе и уже полученые данные там используються для входа в приложение.

Answer (score 0):

Читать модель устройства и данные железа, сохранять, проверять. Так же, как и в декстопных DRM, только в Android гораздо сложнее изменить какой-нибудь id или модель, чтобы закосить под нового юзера - обойти защиту.

Comment: ну всетаки ньюанс что регистрация пользователя как такового происходит не в приложении. Или делать все это непосресдтвенно во время первого входа?

Comment: Видимо, да, во время первого. Остальное мне неведомо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, наверное, привязаться к IMEI. Если это внешний сервис, то по нему и проверять возможность запуска.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил в момент регистрации посылать стороннему сервису в качестве `id`или *payload* (если сервис регистрации поддерживает таковую) идентификатор устройства [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID)

Девайс может и не иметь IMEI, так что представляется что `ANDROID_ID` самый надежный идентификатор. Он генерируется один раз при активации устройства (меняется при сбросе устройства)

Comment: ANDROID_ID может смениться. Например, при заводском сбросе. Например, если устройство с рутом. Например, если телефон из партии, где устройства на всей линейке имеют одинаковый ANDROID_ID.

Comment: На китайских девайсах ANDROID_ID  может быть вообще на всех устройствах, по крайней мере раньше такое бывало